# How to debug vimrc on command terminated

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew

I've recently upgraded to OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) and upgrade everything on Homebrew and even reinstalling vim making sure I have the latest stable version that works with Mavericks. (Vim 7.4)

But I start having this annoying warning every time I tried to editing anything with vim:

```
"~/.vimrc" 497L, 12210C^[[>0;95;c
Command terminated
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I know my `vimrc` might not be correct, but is there a way to debug this? I think it's some system command that I called on vimrc that mess it up, but is there a way to get more debugging info on which commands fail ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Alright, I think I find the answer.

You can always start vim with some debugging info output to a log file:

`vim -V9vim.log ~/.zshrc`

That helped me!

Comment: Where is the log file? `~/V9vim.log`? `~/9vim.log`? `~/vim.log`? `~/zshrc/vim.log`? etc...